# Facebook likes reset to zero

Tags: facebook

I've seen many posts with similar problem but no concrete solution.

I had 38 likes on my website and one day it was reset to 0. Now I've updated the script (as given on FB website) but have lost all my likes.

How can I get my likes back?

Answer (score 4):

> I had 38 likes on my website: http://www.buildingmanager.com.au

According to http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/ you got 37 *shares* right now.

> and one day it was reset to 0. Now I've updated the script (as given on FB website) but have lost all my likes.

In your like button code, you have given a *different URL*,

```
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"
  data-href="http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/sfmportal/" …>
```

– and *that* URL has only one share (http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/sfmportal/)

And [putting your base URL through the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/) shows that you’re a) redirecting to the second URL, and more importantly b) have given the second URL as content of the "og:url" meta tag.

If you want your likes from http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/ to show up using the like button for either of those URLs – then you will have to give *that URL* as "og:url", so Facebook knows you consider this the “actual” Open Graph URL to be liked.

If you are not willing/able to do that, because you want http://www.buildingmanager.com.au/sfmportal/ to be the new, actual URL for your project – then you’ll have a fresh start now, whether you like it or not ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. After changing the url, I got the likes back. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure nothing has changed at your side. Maybe a redirection? It's very unlikely to have Facebook set your likes to zero. But if there is a very slight at your URL, then it would. Maybe some recent plugin you've installed? Or moved your pages/changed URLs of your posts etc. You may use the Facebook debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for more info about your URLs. Hope it helps, because it's just not logical for Facebook to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with one of my websites.

It was fixed by specifying that "/index.php" part after the ".com" to get the likes/shares back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem sometime back. The url in the og:url had **https://...** while the one in the like button element had **http://...**

They should match.